# Unable to select entry by last segment

Tags: segments, ee

I have the following code:

```
{if segment_1  == 'special-offers'}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="products" dynamic="no" url_title="{last_segment}"}
        <link rel="canonical" href="{site_url}{categories limit="1"}{category_url_title}{/categories}/product/{last_segment}" />
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        {/if}
```

This is returning no entries.  If I remove the url_title="{last_segment}" part, I get all the entries in that channel, which Is not what I want.  Can anybody see why I can't limit the results by the last segment?  Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure that your last segment matches the `url_title` of an entry in the `products` channel? Also: is your last segment just the second segment?

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for you help.  For some reason it's decided to start working.  Very odd, I haven't changed anything since yesterday, but it's decided to start working now.

Comment: just guessing, but could possibly caused by the entry having a future date, which in turn could be caused by your server timezone being set incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the date on the entry. Perhaps it has accidentally been set to the future at some point and so only just started working now. Just a thought.